# detecting and measuring lead lag effect

Tags: time-series, statistics

Given two time series data. I remember there is one statistics that tells you one is the leading factor while the other is the lagging factor. However, i do not remember the exact details. correlation is part of its name. I wonder if any one here could help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [lagged correlation or cross correlation](http://www.ltrr.arizona.edu/~dmeko/notes_10.pdf).  Lagged correlation refers to the correlation between two time series shifted in time relative to one another. This measure is useful for studying whether a lagged time series $x_{t-k}$ can be viewed as a good predictor for $y_t$. If you are familiar with R, then you may find the following two links on cross correlation, lagged regression useful: [Cross Correlation Functions and Lagged Regressions](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/74) and [Cross-correlation as Leading indicator](http://www.colorado.edu/geography/class_homepages/geog_4023_s11/Lecture19_TS5.pdf).

As suggested by Professor Eric Zivot, we can also generalize the approach as follows: one can   estimate a [vector autoregression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) involving your variables of interest and then test for [Granger non-causality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality). See the vars 
package and in particular the causality() function.

Comment: first 3 links seem broken in firefox